# How do I let the user specify a number without getting errors thrown back at me?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've created a prime number generator and wanted the user to specify the number of prime numbers generated. I was wondering how I could change "1000" to a raw_input without the program throwing errors back at me as it has been doing. Also how do I save this list generated to a .txt file? Thanks in advance

Code:

```
no_of_primes = 1
candidate = 2
start = 2
list_of_primes = []

while no_of_primes <= 5000:
    result = candidate % start

    if result > 0:
        start +=1

    elif result == 0:
        if start == candidate:
            list_of_primes.append(candidate)
            candidate +=1
            no_of_primes +=1
            start =2
        else:
            candidate +=1
            start = 2

print list_of_primes
```

Comment: Do you mean 5000?  And please let us know which errors the program is "throwing at you."

Comment: sorry, yes 5000. I tried putting "raw_input("How many prime numbers would you like? > ")" instead of 5000 and this doesn't work, as well as replacing it with x and defining it as the previous. @Nix

Comment: Have you read up about exception handling yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, replace the `5000` with a variable (like, say, `primes_to_generate`). Then before the `while` loop, set that variable by calling `int` on the result of `raw_input`. The `int` will convert it from a string to a number, fixing your error:

```
primes_to_generate = int(raw_input("How many to generate? "))
```

You can also use a `try` block to catch errors for if someone, say, types in "ninety" rather than "90":

```
try:
    primes_to_generate = int(raw_input("How many to generate? "))
except ValueError:
    print "Whoa! That's not a number I know!"
    # You'd probably then want to let the user retry
    # by enclosing this whole thing in a loop or something.
```

Comment: ah, that would explain it, it didn't recognise it as a number so couldn't proceed?

Comment: @Barker: Yup. Python has a distinction between numbers and strings; `2 + 3 == 5`, but `"2" + "3" == "23"`. It also doesn't implicitly coerce between them, e.g., `"2" + 3` is an error, because it is often a source of subtle bugs.

Comment: also wrap the int() in a try/except block.  this way you catch invalid calls to int() [ at least in python 2]

Comment: how do you do that exactly? Thanks! @JonathanVanasco